# Question Related categories in magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a main category with four subcategories. Whenever I click on the main category, all four subcategory images are displayed. When I click on any image out of this four, then instead of its description I want a link to the subcategory.

For example, suppose I have a main category `Car` with four subcategories: `Honda`, `Hyundai`, `Suzuki` and `Chevrolet`. When I click on the `Car` category, it should display images of all four subcategories. Now, when I click on `Honda` image, it should redirect to `Honda's` subcategory page, instead of the image description.

Please, answer my query.

Answer (score 1):

Magento's own demonstration store shows how to do this with static blocks.

For example: http://demo.magentocommerce.com/electronics
This is done by changing a category's (in this case, your "main category") Display Mode from "Products only" to "Static block only" and selecting a CMS block to go with it.